# How to package Java program with MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a Java program that uses MYSQL for the database. Every time I want to run the program I must ensure that the MySQL server is running so that JDBC can connect to my database. How can I package my program with a JDBC driver and a copy of MySQL so that it runs in other computers without having to expect the user to install and manually start MySQL separately? I wish to achieve this so that my program will be a portable program with everything correctly and automatically installed by my Java program. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It may be funny answer but as smart as question. Run Ubuntu from your pendrive. Connect external hdd/ssd. Use dd command to create image of your drive. Than swap your hdd and burn your *.img file to other drive. Then take copied drive to other computer and insert your drive. Than boot. Simpler solution is to use SQLite insted of MySQL.

Comment: Why i need ubuntu OS? The program can run in every OS, maybe in linux or maybe in windows. But for now, i want to run my java program in Windows OS.

Comment: I mean, that you could have full-distribution of your app with included os. With windows it is not so simple, but for example freebsd is on bsd license and also support java.